# Eclipse CSS3 Profiler missing autocompletion

Tags: eclipse, css, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Mars on my PHP Project, and I have set the CSS Profiler to be CSS3, but some new attributes are missing from auto completion like 'transition' and 'transform', which I use a lot.

Does anyone have an idea how to add the new CSS3 attributes to Eclipse's Auto completion? If not, can I add or modify a CSS Profiler, so I can manually add them in?

Comment: I have created 2 topics into Eclipse's Forum to no luck, 5 thousand views over there and nobody gives an answer https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1709340/#msg_1709340 I'm just sad that this is actually possible